# How do I inform my neighbor about not cutting grass on my side of the lawn?

Tags: conversations, conflict-aversion, boundaries

I know it's not a big deal for most, but I really do put a lot of effort into having a nice lawn, and our next door neighbour has done a few things that grind my gears, and I do not know how to resolve without creating a grumpy neighbour.

He replaced his front lawn with an extended driveway, while our side is a lawn.

As soon as we moved in, he cut a foot strip off our lawn, and replaced with new sod, so it looks like a nice edge to his property while ours looked mediocre.

Instead of worrying, we simply redid our entire front lawn with new sod to match.

The city-side curb grass we keep nice and thick (3" or so) while he cuts his bare. The issue is that recently he started cutting a full lawnmower width into our side.

I cut the grass twice a week, it's very maintained and definitely the better looking of the two, while he does it once a month, then damages some of our side, even if I just cut 30 minutes ago, he will go over what I just cut and take a strip and turn it yellow and bare.

**How do I approach him without causing a heated neighbor situation?**

Comment: Here is another similar question about a neighbor cutting grass: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8007/uncomfortable-with-neighbor-mowing-our-lawn/8010#8010. While the question is different, the top voted answer may work for you.

Comment: Is that obvious he's cutting into your yard? Most people in my neighborhood wouldn't care, then again, our houses are separated by several feet.

Comment: Yes, it is VERY obvious as there's a very distinct line going from the back yard to the front street, but he oversteps it always by a full mower width.
And definitely not the friendly "oh you're welcome" kind of neighbor. 
I offered to cut his grass once to his adult son as I was doing it, he said for sure, thank you!! I cut it, 5 minutes after the dad (who is the main one I talk about here) comes out and cuts it again... Last time I cut their lawn lol.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't have to be some Machiavellian endeavor here.

1. Strike up conversation casually ("Hey Bill whats been going on?...")
2. After a few minutes of small talk, get to the point, preferably in a way that makes it feel like a favor rather than instructions ("Oh yea, I was hoping you could help me out with something....")
3. State the issue clearly, but kindly, and optionally shift blame to an absent party. That last part may/may not be advisable depending on the their disposition and the situation, but most of the time it's ok. ("Could I ask that you be careful to not mow too much over the property line? I don't mind too much, but the wife is particular about the lawn and on my case...")

The other option would be much more passive aggressive and put up some sort of divider that would make the division clearer and harder to mow over. That seems much more likely to create resentment though.